# How can I query all transaction details of the first 50 customers from a MongoDB server?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

The cluster contains about 240,000 entries of transaction data, inside a local server in my PC.

Cust_ID stands for Customer ID

[image: Sample document structure]

The file contains all transactions done by this customer, followed by transactions done by another customer, and so on. About 3000 customers.

The number of transactions per customer is not the same.

The Cust_IDs are random and unique for each customer, and they are not in any particular order in the cluster.

How can I query the all the transactions made by the first 50 customers in a way where I don't have to manually enter each Customer ID?

By 1st, I mean the following:

Say we have entries like:

```
{
    Cust_ID: "1001",
    Name: "ABC",
    transaction: "1"
}

{
    Cust_ID: "1001",
    Name: "ABC",
    transaction: "3"
}

{
    Cust_ID: "1001",
    Name: "ABC",
    transaction: "6"
}

{
    Cust_ID: "1092",
    Name: "BCD",
    transaction: "23"
}

{
    Cust_ID: "1092",
    Name: "BCD",
    transaction: "12"
}

{
    Cust_ID: "2104",
    Name: "CDE",
    transaction: "234"
}

{
    Cust_ID: "1004",
    Name: "DEF",
    transaction: "3"
}

{
    Cust_ID: "1551",
    Name: "ASD",
    transaction: "54"
}

/*The transaction details of 1st 3 customers would be:*/

{
    Cust_ID: "1001",
    Name: "ABC",
    transaction: "1"
}

{
    Cust_ID: "1001",
    Name: "ABC",
    transaction: "3"
}

{
    Cust_ID: "1001",
    Name: "ABC",
    transaction: "6"
} //customer 1

{
    Cust_ID: "1092",
    Name: "BCD",
    transaction: "23"
}

{
    Cust_ID: "1092",
    Name: "BCD",
    transaction: "12"
} //customer 2

{
    Cust_ID: "2104",
    Name: "CDE",
    transaction: "234"
} //customer 3
```

Comment: "first" according to what order?

Comment: According to the order with which the data is entered.

Comment: You need to have a field in your data such as a counter that reflects the order. MongoDB does not maintain insertion order for collection's documents.

Comment: Are those customer ids ordered numbers (successive) one after the previous. How are they generated?

Comment: I have edited the question to show what I meant. The cluster was made from a CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use an aggregate query to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) them by **Cust_ID** then `$sort` and `$limit` (by 50) on those grouped records.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$Cust_ID",
      books: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "_id": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 50
  }
]);
```